# Me As Child Type In General Function

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a `MustInherit` Parent class with two Child classes which Inherit from the Parent.

How can I use (or Cast) `Me` in a Parent function as the the child type of that instance?

**EDIT:** My actual goal is to be able to serialize (`BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream, Object)`) either of my child classes.  However, "repeating the code" in each child "seems" wrong.

**EDIT2:** This is my Serialize function.  Where should I implement this function?  Copying and pasting to each child doesn't seem right, but casting the parent to a child doesn't seem right either.

```
Public Function Serialize() As Byte()
    Dim bFmt As New BinaryFormatter()
    Dim mStr As New MemoryStream()

    bFmt.Serialize(mStr, Me)

    Return mStr.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: Your parent class/function should have no knowledge of any child classes. Why do you need it to cast to a child class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: Just as you would cast a normal object:

```
If TypeOf Me Is ChildClass1 Then
    Dim x As ChildClass1 = DirectCast(Me, ChildClass1)
    ....
End If
```

Still, doing such a cast in the code of `Parent` is considered very bad practice. Please have a look at the [Template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_pattern), it might be more suitable to what you need, and it's way cleaner than doing such a cast.

Comment: Where should my serialize function be?

Comment: @Steven: In the parent -- *only* in the Parent. Yes, it will serialize the fields of the child as well if the *actual* type of the variable is `ChildClass1`. `BinaryFormatter.Serialize` uses the *dynamic* type of the object passed to it, not the static type of the variable.